# two points movements does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, graphics

here i have two point one of them is fixed and the other is changed by mouse clicking i want the fixed point to move toward the moving one and show its movements in the output ..until now the fixed point (yellow ) does not move to the red

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <stdlib.h> //Needed for "exit" function
   //Include OpenGL header files, so that we can use OpenGL
   #include <glut.h>
   using namespace std;
    void init();
   void display();
   float a = 200.0, b= 200.0;
   void setPoint(float x, float y){
   glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);  //drawing object
   glBegin(GL_POINTS);
   glVertex2f(x,y);
   glEnd();

   }
  int m=50;
  int n=50;
  void setPoint2(int m,int n){
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);  //drawing object
  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  glVertex2f(m,n);
  glEnd();
   }

 void init(){
 glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
 gluOrtho2D(0.0, 400.0, 0.0, 300.0);
   }
 void display(){
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   //defult point
  glPointSize(10.0);
  setPoint(a,b);
  setPoint2(m,n);
  glFlush();
  }
  void update(){
while(a!=m || b!=n){
if(a>m&&b>n)
{
    m++;
    n++;
    setPoint2(m,n);

}
else if(a>m&&b<n)
{
    m++;
    n--;
    setPoint2(m,n);

}
else if(a<m&&b>n)
{
    m--;
    n++;
    setPoint2(m,n);

}
else  if(a<m&&b<n)
{
    m--;
    n--;
    setPoint2(m,n);

}

    //  glTranslatef(m,n,0);    
}


    }
    void mouse(int mouse, int state, int x, int y){
    switch(mouse){
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if(state == GLUT_DOWN){
    cout << x << " -> " << y << endl;

    /*a=x;
    b=y;*/
    a = x/1.0;
    b = 300.0 - (y/1.0);

   glutPostRedisplay();

  }
 break;

   }

  }
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
  glutInitWindowSize(400,300);
  glutInitWindowPosition(200,100);
  glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Program");
  init();
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMouseFunc(mouse);
 //glutTimerFunc(25,update, 0); //Add a timer
 glutMainLoop();
      return 0;
     }
```

while debugging the red point(variable one )appears with mouse clicking the problem with the fixed one(yellow) it did not moves to the red as i want

Comment: I suggest for future questions, you ask questions, talk through the kinds of things you've tried, what you've seen while debugging, and don't just post a bunch of code at once.

Comment: @Rob
i am beginner in openGl and in this site ..thanks :) 
i will add what i have seen in debugigng

Answer (score 0):

The two most glaring problems here are that you don't seem to actually have anything calling the update function, and that if you did, your movement code is specialised to only do diagonal movement, so if the points are in a horizontal or vertical line, they won't move.

It's a while since I used GLUT, but I think the general thing to do is to put your update() logic into the 'idle' callback, and do a `glutPostRedisplay()` at the end of it.

Aside from that the use of so many globals, and especially single-character named globals, whose names mirror that of function argument, is terribly confusing.